# Get the difference between two timestamp rows but in a special format in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, function, time, difference

this is my table...

[image]

In order to autofill 'time_elapse' rows, I would like to get the time difference between the two timestamps rows in a special format: (years/months/days   hours:minutes:seconds:miliseconds) like this...

```
0y/0m/0d   00:00:01.001
```

Currently Im using this trigger...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION timediff()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
tstemp timestamp;

BEGIN
IF NEW.time_type = 'Lap' THEN 
  SELECT t.time FROM table_ebscb_spa_log04 t WHERE t.fn_name = NEW.fn_name AND t.time_type = 'Start' ORDER BY t.stmtserial DESC LIMIT 1 INTO tstemp;
    IF NOT FOUND THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION USING MESSAGE = 'There is not any previous row...';
    ELSE
      NEW.time_elapse := to_char((NEW.time - tstemp), 'yy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS.MS');
    END IF;
END IF;
return NEW;
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

The trigger works, but there is a kinda unwanted behaviour showed in this img...

[image]

The timedifference only counts the days, even if have past a month or a year, it keeps counting only days (483 in the img).
I would like that for every 30 days of timedifference add 1 month and subtract 30 days, also for every 12 months of timedifference add 1 year and subtract 12 months, What would be the easiest way to do that?

Thanks Advanced.

Comment: You can do that with the `to_char` function. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html

Comment: Hi Craig, I used to_char as you said, it works, but there is a kinda unwanted behaviour cuz the timedifference only counts the days, even if have past a month or a year, it keeps counting only days (483 in the img).
I would like that for every 30 days of timedifference add 1 month and subtract 30 days, also for every 12 months of timedifference add 1 year and subtract 12 months, What would be the easiest way to do that? please look I at my question, I uploaded an image of the error. Thanks Advanced.

Comment: Use `justify_interval`

Comment: Hi Craig, I have tried different things, but I have not idea how to apply the "justify_interval" to my code, could you please tell me if there is something I need to change in the way how Im getting the time difference??? Thanks Advanced.

Comment: In my code Im doing this... NEW.time_elapse := to_char((NEW.time - tstemp), 'yy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS.MS')... by doing that I automatically set NEW.time_elapse to be an "interval" right??